# How to register console command from package in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, package, laravel-5

Since Laravel 5, it is interest to me - how to register and use console command from package in Laravel 5.

As in laracast discuss https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5, i create a directory structure, add my package to autoload and create a service provider

```
<?php namespace Goodvin\EternalTree;

use Console\InstallCommand;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class EternalTreeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {

    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerCommands();
    }

    protected function registerCommands()
    {
        $this->registerInstallCommand();
    }

    protected function registerInstallCommand()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('command.eternaltree.install', function($app) {

            return new InstallCommand();
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return [

            'command.eternaltree.install'
        ];
    }
}
```

My InstallCommand.php script stored in /src/Console

```
<?php namespace Goodvin\EternalTree\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class InstallCommand extends Command {

    protected $name = 'install:eternaltree';
    protected $description = 'Command for EternalTree migration & model install.';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fire()
    {
        $this->info('Command eternaltree:install fire');
    }

}
```

I register service provider in app.php & execute dump-autoload. But when i try to execute

```
php artisan eternaltree:install
```

it show me

```
[InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "eternaltree" namespace.
```

I think my command is not registered by service provider, because php artisan list does not show my command. Can anyone explain to me what is the right way to register commands in own package in Laravel 5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a decision, it was simple:

in `registerInstallCommand()` 
Add

```
$this->commands('command.eternaltree.install');
```

Answer (score 35):

It is not required to use a service container and a singleton. You can simply put your command class into the `$this->commands([]);` array into the `boot()` section of your service provider.

Like that :

```
$this->commands([
    Acme\MyCommand::class
]);
```

Comment: Did as You suggested:

- Implemented MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

then
    ```public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->commands([
            LaravelTypesController::class
        ]);
    }```

- LaravelTypesController extends Command with $signature, $description
and handle method, but still don't see command on php artisan | grep

Comment: The Laravel documentation says "Most service providers contain a register and a boot method. Within the register method, you should only bind things into the service container. You should never attempt to register any event listeners, routes, or any other piece of functionality within the register method.". Should the `$this->commands([...]);` be in the `boot()` method?

Comment: In my opinion command registering does not contains logic, it just reference where the command is. So it is not like event registering or functionnality. But it is my opinion (and this solution works :D).

Comment: As per Laravel's current docs (10.x) registering commands should be done in the [`boot()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/packages#commands).

Answer (score 11):

### The Laravel 5.6 [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#commands) say:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        $this->commands([
            FooCommand::class,
            BarCommand::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Add a similar `If` statement to your service provider class.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

You were trying to call `eternaltree:install` but you registered the command as `install:eternaltree`.

Your answer is correct... but there was no need for the `registerCommands()` and `registerInstallCommands()` methods. Keep your code lean by just calling the `commands()` method from within the `register()` method.

Comment: Better late than never, this is the correct answer to the question though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **configure schedule** of a command, in your service provider:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

class YourServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->booted(function () {
            $schedule = $this->app->make(Schedule::class);
            $schedule->command('foo:bar')->everyMinute();
        });
    }

    public function register() { }
}
```